# Eloquent - Return Registry only if it doesn't have a value asossiated in the relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, eloquent-relationship

I have this question, maybe someone can help me :)

```
Student::whereHas('courses.group', function ($query) use ($year) {
            $query->where('year', '!=', $year);
        })->orDoesntHave('courses')->where('active', '=', '1')->get()
```

I have this query in eloquent, it works, but I have a problem. What I really need to get on that query is all the registries `students` that have `groups` associated through the pivot `courses`, in which of all the groups it has, it should return the `student` only if it doesn´t have a `$year` value registered in his groups, or if doesn't have any `courses`. Any idea? :)

Comment: The query seems fine, what is your problem?

Comment: Yeah, that query works fine, but it is not what I need actually, because I want the student only if it doesn't have a group associated that contains the value of $year. For example, if $year is 2021 it should return the student "Kirk" because he has two groups associated each with the year value 2020 and 2019. But it shouldn't return "Lars" because he has two groups associated each with the year value 2020 and 2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WhereHas()` has the inverse logic with `whereDoesntHave()`. You need to change the query logic but should be straight forward, as i understand it this should work.

```
Student::whereDoesntHave('courses.group', function ($query) use ($year) {
    $query->where('year', $year);
})->orDoesntHave('courses')
->where('active', '=', '1')
->get();
```

Comment: I didn´t knew `whereDoesntHave` existed, thank you so much ,you saved my life :) Btw: The last `where` statement worked only if i moved it behind the last `get()`.

Comment: super :) remember to accept the answer if it helped